# Can a polynomial with no positive roots have variations in its signs in the expanded form?

Tags: polynomials

I found this [proof](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/fta/ROS2.shtml) for the **Descartes' Rule of Signs.**

Towards the end the author writes this:

> Now return to our original polynomial, $$f(x) = x_n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_1x + a_0.$$
>    We can express *f*(*x*) in factored form as
>   $$f(x) =N(x)(x - p_1)(x - p_2) ... (x-p_m)$$
>   where $N(x)$ has no positive roots (but may, of course, nevertheless have variations in sign), and the $p_i$ are the $m$ positive roots of $f(x)$, listed repeatedly, if necessary, according to their multiplicity.

I wanted to know how $N(x)$ could have variations in signs if it has no positive roots.

What I assumed is $N(x)$ will have negative roots which will be of the form $(x+k)$ or they will have complex roots, which will be of the form $(x^{2n}+k)$, where n is a positive integer and k is a positive real number, in the factorized polynomial. In this case, I see that all of the signs of coefficients in the expanded polynomial format will be positive and there would be **no sign variations**.

How is my assumption wrong? Is there an example of a polynomial without positive roots but with sign variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have failed to consider complex roots that aren't wholly imaginary, whose corresponding quadratic factors in $N(x)$ might have negative linear terms. For example, if $f(x)=x^2-x+1$ then $N(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Oh yeah yes! Since the proof is based on the number of sign changes, can we also say that the number of sign changes in N(x) is an even number?

Comment: @TanmayGujar Yes.

Answer (score 1):

How about $x^2-x+1$? Its roots are complex (with positive real part), but it has no positive real roots.